# Accessing and monitoring log file in POX controller

Tags: logfile, sdn, pox

I want to do some analysis on log file in POX controller and I have to do it online. For that, I need the log file of this controller that accumulates online. (For example recording information while h1 ping h2) 
Can any body help me to find the log file in pox with in network information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you need the log files and not the statistics for ports, queues etc?

Comment: @SotirisTsartsaris: I think that is also good for me, could you please tell me more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add listeners for the stats from switches. Add them like so

```
core.openflow.addListenerByName("FlowStatsReceived", self._handle_flowstats_received)
core.openflow.addListenerByName("PortStatsReceived", self._handle_portstats_received)
core.openflow.addListenerByName("QueueStatsReceived", self._handle_qeuestats_received)
```

And in some class methods later

```
def _handle_qeuestats_received (self, event):
        """
        handler to manage queued packets statistics received
        Args:
            event: Event listening to QueueStatsReceived from openflow
        """
        stats = flow_stats_to_list(event.stats)
        # log.info("QueueStatsReceived from %s: %s", dpidToStr(event.connection.dpid), stats)
```

and

```
def _handle_portstats_received(self,event):
    """
    Handler to manage port statistics received
    Args:
        event: Event listening to PortStatsReceived from openflow
    """
    print event.stats
```

and a method for flow stats. You will get the point. For a full example check https://github.com/tsartsaris/pythess-SDN/blob/master/pythess.py

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a question. Is it efficient to use a log file then send it to Apache Spark and do some machine learning on it? Or it is better to use the mentioned method by you?

Comment: I can not answer that. It is trial by error in my opinion